# Getting a loop when using link_to :back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I have this structure for the table course:

Search page -> Result Page -> Edit Page -> Show page

When i go from result page to a specific course edit page, i edit it, and end up on the show page, but when i hit back, i get a loop from show to edit, and back to show and so on.

I want the edit page to back to the result page if it came from there.

im using this on both:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you actually update your record having edited it you're likely to be doing a redirect from an update action via a put request to show. Even if you're not, and if you're defying convention and updating from the show action, you're trying to navigate to a post action with a get request. If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to edit from either the search result or the show page. What you should do is define a method that allows you to store a location in the session on demand. Put it in the application controller and it will be available to all of your controllers.

```
# copy this into your application_controller.rb file :
private
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

#copy this to the top of your item_controller.rb file:
before_filter :store_location, :only => [:search, :show]

#replace your <%= link_to "Back", :back %> with
<%= link_to 'back', session[:return_to] -%>
```

Comment: I tried the simpler part of your explanation, ending with the same result, probably did something wrong, since i got a little confused with the explanation xD. I'd like it to work like a stack, so when i come from search, i edit, end up in show page, then when i hit back, and back again, i end up on the search result. And im gonna remove the edit link on the show page to reduce problems.

Comment: There's only one explanation really and you'd need to do everything I explained. I'll add some comments to my answer. :)

Comment: I had to adjsut some stuff, because just like that it didn't work.
I used another session variable, wich is loaded every time i enver the search page, to check if the search was acessed before. Its not very pretty but it works, thank you for the help ^^

Comment: You'd want `request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] ` instead of `request.request_uri`. And it is also possible to use `session[:return_to] || url_for(:back)` in the `link_to` so there's a fallback in case something odd happened.